# Object Oriented Analysis & Design

Tags: oop, uml, class-design, data-modeling, object-oriented-analysis

I'm looking for a **video tutorial/training or even lectures** on Object Oriented Analysis & Design.
I don't need explanation for UML and Use cases. I want a full software life cycle explained.

I already read [Head First: Object Oriented Analysis & Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678)

The book actually had all I was looking for:

Requirement gathering, Use case diagrams, Class diagrams all applied to a real project.

I'm looking for something similar in which all these topics are explained practically of a real life full project.

Comment: It is very hard to fulfill your requirement. Only real experience can teach all these together.

Comment: @thinksteep I know what you mean, but I want to see a full cycle for developing a software like they did in Head First: Object Oriented Analysis & Design.

Comment: Instead of looking for real word documentation, I would suggest this, Based on knowledge you gained from Head first, assume you are doing a project (could be any project like as simple as calculator (or) as big as banking application), try to fill in the content related to your assumed application in places of head first application. Within couple of refinements I am sure you will be confident that you know how it works. Last thing, real world cases are not so different from what you are going to do in this process.

Comment: Similar questions: [What books do you suggest for understanding object oriented programming design deeply?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574001/what-books-do-you-suggest-for-understanding-object-oriented-programming-design-d), [Object design in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401330/object-design-in-net)

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan I'm not looking for books. I want video tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youtube has a video - lecture 9 and 10 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uH7wh9f2hyo will cover aspects of OOAD.

But u better read a uml book or Fowlers site on uml - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/uml.html

Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a video tutorial, Simon Bennett's [Object Oriented System Analysis and Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Object-Oriented-Systems-Analysis-Design-Using/dp/0077110005) begins describing two case studies which they follow through the analysis and design stages throughout the book, was very helpful to me in terms of which way to go about projects as well as giving an in depth look at systems development and design.